# How to execute powershell script from FAKE - F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, f#-data, f#-fake

I am migrating MSBuild code to FAKE - and I am not able to execute powershell script from fake ,below is the code of MSBuild file to be written in FAKE :

```
<Target Name="VersionConfig"> 
    <Exec IgnoreExitCode="false" LogStandardErrorAsError="true" StandardErrorImportance="high" Command="powershell -File &quot;$(BuildRoot)\DeployScripts\scripts\AdminScripts\VersionUpdateFile.ps1&quot;  -path &quot;$(BuildSolutionVersioningConfig)&quot; -majorVersion &quot;$(BuildNumberMajor)&quot; -minor &quot;$(BuildNumberMinor)&quot; -build &quot;$(BuildNumber)&quot; -revision &quot;$(BuildNumberRevision)&quot;"/>
</Target>
```

How to write this in FAKE , I'm new to FAKE and have not used F# much, so forgive me if this should be obvious.

If anyone can help , that would be really helpful.

Thank You .

Comment: What are you trying to do? FAKE has its own helpers to modify and [assembly information and versions](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-assemblyinfohelper.html). Have you checked the [Generating AssemblyInfo files](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/assemblyinfo.html) section?

Comment: thank you for the help , but actually I am new to all this stuff , and right now as an intern I am working on it . So , I was just confused whether version.config file gets updated when I change buildinfo.cs using CreateCSharpAssemblyInfo or do I need to change version.config  ,because in MSBuild file , version.config file is being updated by this powershell script .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Fake.ProcessHelper` namespace](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-processhelper.html) in FAKE is what you're looking for. The documentation won't tell you this, but `Fake.ProcessHelper` is [marked with the `AutoOpen` attribute](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/8a0082b3cea5849e1ba1fbdb014f4197aa62d09a/src/app/FakeLib/ProcessHelper.fs#L1), which means that all the functions listed in that API reference page I linked are available to you from your FAKE build script, without you needing any explicit `open` statements to use them. You use it like this:

```
let inQuotes s = sprintf "\"%s\"" s

Target "Sample" (fun _ ->
  let retCode =
    ExecProcess
      (fun info ->
        info.Name <- "powershell.exe"  // Don't know if you need full path here
        info.WorkingDirectory <- getBuildParam "BuildRoot"
        info.Arguments <-
          [ "-File"; getBuildParam "BuildRoot" + "\DeployScripts\scripts\AdminScripts\VersionUpdateFile.ps1" |> inQuotes;
            "-path"; getBuildParam "BuildSolutionVersioningConfig" |> inQuotes;
            "-majorVersion"; getBuildParam "BuildNumberMajor" |> inQuotes;
            "-minor"; getBuildParam "BuildNumberMinor" |> inQuotes;
            "-build"; getBuildParam "BuildNumber" |> inQuotes;
            "-revision"; getBuildParam "BuildNumberRevision" |> inQuotes
          ] |> separated " "
      )
      (TimeSpan.FromMinutes 5.0)
  if retCode <> 0 then
    failwith (sprintf "PowerShell exited with non-zero exit code %d" retCode)
)
```

A couple notes:

- Notice how I declared a custom `inQuotes` helper function to make the `info.Arguments` list look nicer.
- [More info on the `separated` function I used](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-stringhelper.html).
- [More info on the `getBuildParam` function I used](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-environmenthelper.html).

Comment: This will run Powershell like an external process. It's possible to create a Powershell pipeline in code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Good point. For Powershell, it's probably best to look at that script, see what it does, and then turn it into a proper pipeline. And in the case of this script, your point about the ["Generating AssemblyInfo files" documentation](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/assemblyinfo.html) is also good: John Fernandes should probably convert this particular script to use `CreateCSharpAssemblyInfo` instead. **But**... as a general rule, if you want to invoke an external process and there isn't already a FAKE function to help you, then you want to use the `ProcessHelper` functions.

Comment: PowerShell though isn't an external process. You can host it in your own process. In fact, it works almost like an F# pipeline, with each commandlet reading and producing objects. Each `.AddCommand` works like a `|> Seq....`. Executing script files is also possible, by reading the entire file and using `AddScript(scriptText)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a [Powershell pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx) in any .NET application with the classes of the [System.Management.Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation(v=vs.85).aspx) namespace. You can use that pipeline to execute commands locally or on a remote machine.

The following target retrieves the list of processes and prints them. It's the F# equivalent of the documentation example for the PowerShell class:

```
Target "ProcTest" (fun _ ->
    PowerShell.Create()    
            .AddCommand("get-process")
            .Invoke()
            |> Seq.map(fun result->(  result.Properties.["ProcessName"].Value,
                                      result.Properties.["ID"].Value))
            |> Seq.iter (fun (name,id)->printfn "%-24O %O" name id)
)
```

The is a quick & dirty module I use to execute commands (specifically chocolatey commands) on a remote server. The only thing you need to make it work on the local machine is to *remove* the `ComputerName` parameter:

```
#r "System.Management.Automation"

module MyPowershell =

    let InvokeRemote server command =
        let block = ScriptBlock.Create(command)
        let pipe=PowerShell.Create()    
                .AddCommand("invoke-command")
        pipe.AddParameter("ComputerName", server)            
            .AddParameter("ScriptBlock", block)
            .Invoke() 
            |> Seq.map (sprintf  "%O")
            |> Seq.iter (fun line ->
                                let tracer=if line.Contains("not installed") then
                                                traceError 
                                        else 
                                                trace
                                tracer line)
        pipe.Streams.Error |> Seq.iter (traceError << sprintf "%O" )
```

The pipeline is represented by the [PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx) class. The steps to construct it are :

1. Create a PowerShell pipeline with [PowerShell.Create()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell.create(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. Create a ScriptBlock with the command you want to execute. You don't need a ScriptBlock for all commands. In this case, `ScriptBlock` contains the script I want to execute remotely.
3. Add what you want to execute. In my case, I want to run a single `invoke-command` command
4. Add parameters. In this case, it's `-ComputerName myServer` and `-ScriptBlock ...` with the block to execute.
5. Run the pipeline with [PowerShell.Invoke()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182449(v=vs.85).aspx)
6. Parse the results for possible warning messages that didn't make it to the Error stream

PowerShell errors are sent to the `Error` stream, which makes error handling easier.

Executing a command on the local machine can be a lot simpler:

```
let InvokeRemote command =
    let pipe=PowerShell.Create()    
            .AddCommand(command)
    pipe.Invoke() 
        |> Seq.map (sprintf  "%O")
        |> Seq.iter (fun line ->
                            let tracer=if line.Contains("not installed") then
                                            traceError 
                                    else 
                                            trace
                            tracer line)
    pipe.Streams.Error |> Seq.iter (traceError << sprintf "%O" )
```